# Adding values from C# to DIV via JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript

The last module of my chat script is passing values from C# code to JavaScript and JavaScript will post values to the DIV. Before I used DataBinder but when using it directly C# code is taken by AJAX's update panel. Now, I need a set of Array values to be passed via Timer Tick function to JavaScript. How can I pass Arrays from C# to JavaScript using `<%= %>`. A part of my code follows.

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            MyConnection.Close();
        }
        MyConnection.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select message from messages where name=?", MyConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = "human";
        OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string messagev = dr[0].ToString();
            // What should I do here?
        }
        MyConnection.Close();
    }
```

I don't want values to directly to be sent to the DIV. First it must be sent to JavaScript and then it must go to DIV.

**For more clarification**

I need C# to retrieve data from backend and to pass that data to client side (i.e. JavaScript) from JavaScript it has to be forwarded to DIV layer.

Comment: You could be interrested in that blog post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Comment: Javascript and HTML are the same layer. A `DIV` tag is just that, a tag in your HTML markup. Make your AJAX call to your ASP.Net application, return your serialized data (JSON or XML) and then use Javascript to stuff the DIV.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am going to suggest the JQuery approach and get rid of the server-side timer. Using JQuery and the JQuery.Timer plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/ you can do this easier in my opinion and it will be nicer on the client end.

In your aspx page you have the element to display output:

```
<span id="status" style="display:none"></span>
```

and also a reference to JQuery, JQuery.Timer.js, and then your code to call the c# web method.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var timer = $.timer(getMessage, 10000);
        timer.play();
    })

    function getMessage() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: 'message-service.asmx/getDBMessages',
            data: "{}",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: getMessageSuccess,
            error: getMessageError
        })
    }

    function getMessageError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       $('#status').html(errorThrown).show();
    }

    function getMessageSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#status').html(data.d).show();
    }
</script>
```

I would use a web-service for the server side db message retrieval:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://site.com/service")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class contact_service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string getDBMessages()
    {
        try
        {
 if (MyConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            MyConnection.Close();
        }
        MyConnection.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select message from messages where name=?", MyConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = "human";
        OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string messagev = dr[0].ToString();
        }
        MyConnection.Close();
return messagev;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this makes sense. I created a web-server (asmx) and created my server-side code to return a string. In the aspx markup I use JQuery to start a timer for 10 seconds and then an .ajax post to poll the service, retrieve the message and display it. No page refresh and much less hacky from my perspective.

Comment: I wouldn't have database calls as a part of a web request handler. It's generally not scalable. I'd leave the OPs timer based DB request code as it is, but have it populate some sort of cache. The have the webmethod, for the ajax call you added above, grab the data from the cache.

Comment: Agreed, but for the purposes of the question asked I did not want to deviate from the original db implementation too far choosing to just copy/paste his already written server-side code into the web-method.

Comment: Typically an error with the server-side code so you should look into the web method or web service you have implemented. Also, check your CustomErrors web.config setting so you can get the full error details back, not just the generic "Internal Server Error".

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the ID of your div is div1, you can do the following

```
div1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(dr[0].ToString()) + "<br />");
```

That will append the Message text to your Div

Comment: This is a good idea but I am getting an error `The name 'div1' does not exists in the current context` Of course my DIV name is div1.

Comment: @Madcoder. Add runat="server" at your div1, like this : <div id="Div1" runat="server"></div>.

Comment: @GuilhermeJSantos, Shai - Thanks! Its working but when using `+ "<br />"` I am getting an error `invalid arguments` when I remove it, its working but no new line to separate.

Comment: Yeah got it by change to `Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(dr[0].ToString() + "<br/>"));`

Comment: Above code worked. But for my function I need JavaScript to be a mediator.

Comment: @Madcoder.: Keep in mind you're outputting javascript. `<br />` is an inappropriate line break in javascript. Instead, inject at the end: `+ Environment.NewLine);`

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to get something into your javascript code. You can make an ajax call from javascript and have the server return what you need (as a normal string or maybe as JSON). Or you can build your javascript code dynamicaly on the server on the original request.
Looking at your code, I think the first method is the way to go. So instead of having the timer function on the server, write a timed function in javascript and poll the server via ajax for new messages.

Comment: Yah, SignalR is probably the way to go. This just looks sub-optimal to me, with a server-side timer... unless only 2-3 people will be using this. If SignalR isn't going to work, at least a client-side poll + AJAX should be used.

Answer (score 3):

You can try RegisterStartupScript to call your javascript function, passing the 'messagev' variable along with that call.

See more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought; you can use Flash or an applet to have socket communication to javascript.
A websocket implementation for Flash is found here: https://github.com/y8/websocket-as. Might be nice for chat, maybe overkill though, depends.

Comment: That may make more complicated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use Long Polling to get push notification.
Read about Long Polling from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

You can find a great example [here](http://jacob4u2.posterous.com/mvc-3-long-polling-comet-chat-example), which explains both the server side and client side [implementation](https://bitbucket.org/jacob4u2/mvcchatsite/src).
If, your are using HTML 5, I would suggest you have a look at [Web Sockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

For server side technology you can use C# , but a certain Node.js is making all the right noises for this kind of work

Answer (score 0):

What if you used a hidden HTML control on the page that you set in the Timer1_Tick method and use that to read in the value in your javascript function.
    `hiddenControl.Text = dr[0].ToString();`
And then in the javascript function 
    `var data = document.getElementById('hiddenControl').value` 
And then here you can add that data to your div however you please.

Answer (score 0):

Use ScriptManager to and register the client script block..

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                this.Page,
                this.GetType(),
                "WebUserControlSript",
                "FunctionABC('" + messagev + "')",
                true);
```

And in .aspx page use the following javascript:

```
FunctionABC(message)

{
     append "message" to div here..
}
```

Thanks,

Regards,

Dhaval Shukla

Comment: Thanks for your code Mr.Dhaval. In client side this code `<script type="text/javascript"> function FunctionABC(message) { var elem = document.getElementById('div1'); elem.innerHTML = message; } </script>` will be enough? But this JavaScript is not working can you please help me in building it.

Comment: Can you please try it with following code:    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function FunctionABC(message)
    {
        alert(message);
        $('#abc').html(message);
    }
</script>
<div id="abc">
    
    </div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>    you should write the div outside of form tag inorder to make it work..

Comment: Please note that, in above given comment example i have registered clientscript on button click..

Comment: The you have given is working but its able to retrieve only the first value from database. But how to retrieve all values?

Comment: One work around for you is you can create an html string and pass it as parameter to javascript and append it to div as shown:  
string messagev = "<table><tr><th>" + message + "</th><th>" + messageev1 + "</th><th>" + messageev2 + "</th><th>" + messageev3 + "</th></tr></table>";
Here, messageev1, messageev2, etc are the string object in which some values are assigned..